# Blender 2.8 December 24 Grease Pencil convert to geometry is gray out and it's not working

Tags: grease-pencil, conversion

Hi everyone I don't know if it's a bug or not but I'm using latest version of Blender 2.8 December 24 blender-2.80.0-git.4c5e76025d83-windows64 and I can't convert my strokes to geometry at all they all are gray out, disabled!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to report this issue to developer.blender.org, as it sounds like more of a bug of the latest builds rather than anything else.

Comment: I did, it was a bug and they fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Just downloaded the December 25th Beta build and now the option to convert strokes to geo is completely gone. Bummer, just when I had some time to play with it. Hope it'll be back soon...

Edit: not gone, moved from Edit to Object mode

https://developer.blender.org/rBf5166233dbaa3f70dcd019e8d76a924651841d75